# Autenticação em arquitetura Microservices com C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt, microsserviços

Como fazer uma autenticação de usuário utilizando o padrão *API* *Gateway*? já li vários artigos porém não acho um exemplo de código utilizando **Web API 2** e os que vi utilizando o *asp* *net* *core* só faz a primeira autenticação do usuário, ou seja, como é o contexto do usuário logado nos microserviços *"internos"*, segue cenário:

- Microserviço de Vendas
- Microserviço de Estoque

Imagine que os usuários podem ou não acessar os dois microservices e cada usuário possui uma *conta* identificada com um Guid, a minha dúvida é como "Api Gateway" autentica o usuário e monta o contexto dele para que os microserviços internos possam identificar quais recursos o mesmo tem acesso.

Comment: Essa autenticação pode ser feita por tokens? Olhe esse diagrama: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/secure-net-microservices-web-applications/media/image2.png. Veja a implementaçao de segurança para o Service Basket e Catalog

Comment: Sim, pode ser feito via Token, na verdade o Servidor de autenticação já retorna um token,  porém como fazer as outras APIS reconhecer esse token que é meu problema. Obrigado por me ajudar.

Comment: Você avaliou o uso do [IdentityServer4](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/index.html). Ele é um framework de autenticação opensource que cobre o seu cenário.

Comment: Você pode utlizar o [Ocelot](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/implement-api-gateways-with-ocelot) ou [Steeltoe](https://steeltoe.io). Na documentação da Microsoft você pode encontrar algumas dicas [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/secure-net-microservices-web-applications/)